# how to get node.js v0.10.12 's include files

Tags: node.js, add-on, include-path

I download the node js v0.10.12 tar file ,untar,configure make and install but I can't find the Include fils for making cpp addons 
why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't find them, as is [explained in the documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html):

> Node statically compiles all its dependencies into the executable. When compiling your module, you don't need to worry about linking to any of these libraries.

You can simply include them as:

```
#include <node.h>
#include <v8.h>

using namespace v8;
```

Though, to compile an addon, you'll need [`node-gyp`](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp) installed globally, [its runtime dependencies](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp#installation) for your OS, and a [`binding.gyp`](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp#the-bindinggyp-file) for your project. Then:

```
node-gyp configure
node-gyp build
```

Or:

```
node-gyp rebuild
```

Read through the ["Hello World" example/tutorial](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_hello_world) for more info.

Comment: Thanks ,but there's no node.lib and uncopy include files when I run make & make install to install node on MacOS.Do u know why?

Comment: @XinKing Again, you won't find such files. Node does not install with any library files for compiling addons. As it says, the libraries are embedded within the `node` executable. This does make it peculiar if you're trying to use an IDE to develop addons, but a text editor and a terminal (to execute `node-gyp` commands) should work fine.